# Can i upgrade my mid 2012 macbook pro to use DDR4 ram ?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, upgrade, memory

Can i upgrade my mid 2012 macbook pro to use DDR4 ram ? Checking Apple > About this Mac > Memory i got the following

```
Your Mac contains 2 memory slots, each of which accepts
a 1600 MHz DDR3 memory module.
```

Which seems to suggest not, but i wondered if DDR4 was even around at the time my mac was made, is Ram a backwards compatible upgrade like placing a Sata SSD in a 10 year old device ?

Comment: DDR3 and DDR4 have [different chip carrier designs](http://www.ocinside.de/review/adata_premier_4x4gb_ddr4_2133/) are are not physically the same. On the page above, scroll down to the **DDR4 vs DDR3 …** section.

Comment: It is NOT a duplicate. The linked question was posed for 2010 model, this question is for 2012 which has a completely different processor, graphic card and  RAM requirements. They might look the same, but there is a huge difference between them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the Mid-2012 MacBook Pro is in no way upgradable to DDR4 RAM.

To use DDR4 RAM a lot of things must be compatible with DDR4 - one of those is the CPU itself. The Intel CPU in the mid-2012 MacBook Pro does not support DDR4 RAM.

And no, DDR4 was not around in mid-2012. It was released to the market in 2014.